# Remote Window doesn't receive message

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, sendmessage

I'm trying to use same code (program C) calling TreeView_GetRoot (TVM_GETNEXTITEM message) against a TreeView in other programs (A and B) in order to manipulate them.

Program A can receive the message (I can see the message from spy++).

But for program B, seems it cannot receive the message, return value is 'undefined' from VC debug window, meanwhile no message shows up in spy++.
(Spy++ shows messages properly for manually click on the TreeView)

Both of the 2 programs and spy++ are 32 bit.

Furthermore, Winspector (like spy++) can show the item count for TreeView in program A, but not for the one in program B. I suspect it is caused by the same reason.

Do you know what's the possibility it could be?

Comment: Which program is *sending* the message? Program A? Or a different program entirely?

Comment: UIPI (see [Windows Integrity Mechanism Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx)).

Comment: @CodyGray A different program. Let's say it's C.

Comment: Then IInspectable already has your answer. What does `GetLastError` say? 5 == access denied because it was blocked by UIPI.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) notes, that message sending is subject to UIPI (see [Windows Integrity Mechanism Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx)):

> Message sending is subject to UIPI. The thread of a process can send messages only to message queues of threads in processes of lesser or equal integrity level.

The documentation also notes, how errors due to UIPI violations are reported:

> When a message is blocked by UIPI the last error, retrieved with [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx), is set to 5 (access denied).

The following lists potential solutions:

- Use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). Under certain conditions, UI automation programs can bypass UIPI restrictions.
- Run the controlling application at a higher integrity level. This is not recommended, and should be seen as a last resort only.

Comment: Does UI Automation require modification to the target program (B and C)? They are not under my control.

Comment: @user1633272: UI Automation requires, that the target programs expose the required interfaces. This is true for all standard Windows controls, as well as several frameworks (MFC, naturally, because it wraps standard controls, Qt, etc). To investigate whether a particular program exposes the necessary interfaces, use the [Inspect tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) to find out.

Comment: I can see the controls and their values from Inspect.exe. I think it could be done by UI Automation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: TreeWalker.GetFirstChild returns object for program A, but returns null for program B. Any suggestion?

Comment: @user1633272: Did you read about the requirements explained in the [document I linked to in my answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx)? In particular, does your application *"have a digital signature that can be verified using a digital certificate that chains up to a trusted root in the local machine Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store"*?